# [UNIX] : Do I need to add all libraries in my project's makefile, that are used from a library, used in my project?

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, linker

Ha, this sounds more complicated, than it actually is. Here's what I mean:

Suppose I write an application, that uses threads. In this application, I don't use the `pthreads` directly, but I use a wrapper, that uses `pthreads`. So, in this wrapper's makefile, `-lpthread` must be included. And the question - do I need to include `-lpthread` in my project, or it's not necessary? Or it depends? If so, on what?

I'm asking this, because I've seen this a lot and I don't think it's necessary.. The same for `-std=c++0x`?

---

Also, I had a problem with the Informix C++ interface, as it relies on lib, called `DMI`, which is built on the top of `ESQL/C`. When I removed these libraries and use only the real one, I got linker problems(problems with finding the libs). When I added `dmi` and `esql/c`, everything was fine.

Does this answers my question (with "YES"), or I could've done something wrong, other than this (I'm newbie with makefiles (: )

---

[source](http://tutortan.blogspot.com/2007/04/makefiles.html): "Makefiles are something of an arcane topic--one joke goes that there is only one makefile in the world and that all other makefiles are merely extensions of it. I assure you, however, that this is not true; I have written my own makefiles from time to time."

This made me think if all included libraries in the makefiles (of my company's projects) are necessary, or this is for "historical reasons"

---

**EDIT**: The wrapper around `pthread` is linked static, and the `Informix` lib was dynamically linked, if this matters.
Also, the OS is RHEL (4 and 5), but I need to know if this depends on the OS and on the way of linking (dynamic or static)

Comment: Libraries are capable of having transitive dependencies. Now, several Linux variants, support it, yet some have started disabling it again (like Fedora). Some OS's never had them. For clarity it seems reasonable to require that all libraries be used. However, build systems like automake/cmake take care of this for you.

Comment: The question isn't very clear as to whether this wrapper is a static or a dynamic library, or merely a collection of object files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you do a mistake:

> So, in this wrapper's makefile,
>   -lpthread must be included

A static library created by the `ar` tool is just a collection of object files in a special file format that is recognised later by the linker. This collection of code isn't linked to any library. Specifying `-lpthread` when compiling each of the source files at this stage is pointless because no linking is done.

Only when calling the linker to produce the final executable out of all libraries and object files, you need to pass the particular libraries with the `-l` option. Note that the compiler is not invoked at this step, and `-l` is not a compiler option, but a linker option.

For example, this only invokes the linker because no source files are supplied:

```
gcc -o myprog main.o -lmylib -lpthread
```

By contrast, compiling a source file to an object file and specifying a library is pointless because no linking is going to be performed:

```
gcc -c wrapper_source.c -lpthread
```

Comment: So, let's generalize: I don't need to include the `-lpthread` in the wrapper's makefile, if I make a `.o` file from it, bеcause I'll `link` with it later and this option must be included in my project's makefile, right? But if I compile the wrapper to `.a` or `.so` and I link with it dynamically, I need to add `-lpthread` in the wrapper's makefile and **not** in my project's makefile? Correct me if I'm wrong. Мерси (:

Comment: In short, you should never try to link to a library when creating a static library or compile to an object file. Linking is about resolving all symbols in the executable code. Благодаря :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the libraries are somehow included in the wrapper you are using, the answer is YES you will need to include them in the makefile of the program that uses the wrapper.

For instance if the wrapper is a .o, it hasn't been linked to anything yet. However, if the wrapper is a .so or .a, it may include the libraries depending on how you constructed it. I think [**ar**](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ar%201) is responsible for this kind of things.

Comment: "However, if the wrapper is a .so or .a, it may include the libraries depending on how you constructed it" - I'm not sure on this...

Comment: Static linking and archiving.

Answer (score 0):

All dynamically linked libraries must be present.

Usually, when your application uses a wrapper in a shared library, is not aware of the wrapper's makefile and cannot find out that it needs to include pthread. On the other hand, the linker working on your application usually does want to make sure there are no undefined symbols left in the project.

Therefore you will have to add directives for all shared libraries your code depends on.

Comment: Dynamically linked?  I thought the idea behind a dynamically linked library was that you could compile the rest separately, and add the library at runtime.  Did you mean directly or indirectly linked?