# Is it completely safe to remove unused libraries as reported by ldd?

Tags: dynamic, makefile, g++, ld

I'm cleaning up a rotted source tree, and I try to make each executable and each shared library to link only with the libraries they use directly.

In order to do that, I `ldd -u- r` the binary output, and remove the reported libraries from the makefile.

For example:

```
$ ldd -u -r ./libA.so
Unused direct dependencies:
        /usr/local/lib/libB.so
        /usr/local/lib/libC.so
        /lib/tls/libpthread.so.0
$ sed -i'' -e 's/-lB//' -e 's/-lC//' Makefile
```

Well, of course `libpthread` is really needed (and is anyway implicitly included with `-pthread`), but the rest of the libraries reported by `ldd` can be safely remove.

Are there implications to my optimization? Is it completely safe?

Comment: Depends on if `libB` and `libC` are used by another library, that is (directly) used. You could see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664338/c-unix-do-i-need-to-add-all-libraries-in-my-projects-makefile-that-are

Comment: @Kiril: That only applies to static libraries. Dynamic libraries know their dependencies.

Comment: @Kiril, do you mean what I wrote in the answer below? If so it's not so bad, as I'll find out about it when the compilation fails, and fixing it is a very good idea anyhow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is safe*, unless one thing happens (which is, thankfully, under your control).

If the application loads additional symbols with `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT,...)`, it will search currently loaded shared libraries for the appropriate symbol (function).  If its intent is to load the symbol from one of these libs you want to remove (**and** there was no prior `dlopen()` call), the application won't find it, and may misbehave.

Note, however, `dlsym()` is used very seldom (and you may check if it's used via ldd), and it's even more seldom to use it without a prior call to `dlopen()`, so in nearly all cases you may safely remove unused libraries.  It will significantly improve the portability of your application.

---

*<sup>by "safe" I mean "likely to work if there were no build-time errors". Build-time ramifications of removing libraries are too easy to detect to account for them.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One implication I can think of, is, that there might be an implicit dependency that is used only by an executable, but is specified in a library. For example.

```
$ cat a.cc
int fa(){return 42;}
$ gcc -shared a.cc -o liba.so -ltermcap
$ cat main.cc
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termcap.h>
int main() {
        tgetent(0,getenv("TERM"));
        printf("terminal is %d columns\n",tgetnum("co"));
}
$ gcc main.cc -o main # we didn't mention -ltermcap
/tmp/ccercfhS.o(.text+0x27): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `tgetent'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$ # we mentioned -ltermcap by using -la
$ # if we'll remove -ltermcap from liba the project won't compile
$ gcc main.cc -o main -L. -la 
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
terminal is 237 columns
```

However this is not such a bad error, as it'll always be detected and fixed early by you, and not by the customers.

And anyhow, you should [include what you use](http://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/wiki/InstructionsForUsers#Include_What_You_Use) so it's very good to have `main.cc` link with `termcap` directly.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would do a test run or two using strace like so

strace -e open myprog >strace.out 2>&1

Then check the strace output to see which libraries are actually opened. That means any open() call that does not return -1.

Comment: I don't see how would it help. `ldd` and `nm` can give me all this information for free.

Comment: Sorry but ldd can't. A running application might dynamically load libraries that are not link time dependencies. And ldd cannot know what the current directory is during excecution time so things like RPATH using $ORIGIN can't be correctly evaluated. If nothing else, just grep the output for opens that are not equal to -1 and make sure that they look right. Strace is very useful for a final positive check that everything is right.

Comment: OK, so `ldd` and `ack ldopen`. strace have the disadvantage of checking only the piece of code you used in this specific unit test.

Comment: Use a code coverage tool to make sure that your unittest is exhaustive. Don't release code that has not been thoroughly unittested

Comment: Microsoft don't follow your advice, a team leader told me he don't necessarily thrive to 100% coverage. However what are you doing with existing project? If the project was good, we would have checked for `ld -u -r` in the build process. `ack ldopen` gives the same results of `strace`, is cheaper, and more exact, so I see no reason to use `strace`.

Answer (score 0):

For me there seems to be the additional implication that ldd will display all libraries it can't find as unused (they could have been there at build time, so no errors here).

So **no**, it is not safe to rely on the results of `ldd -u`!

(tested with ldd 2.27 under Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.2 and ldd 2.24 under Devuan ascii)

Answer (score 0):

You already found there are false positives because libpthread.so was needed but flagged as being unneeded.  So you can't assume the others can be safely removed.