# Duplicated steps when linking to static libraries in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, ubuntu, static-libraries, eclipse-cdt, cross-compiling

I’m cross compiling my C projects using Eclipse CDT/CodeSourcery Lite on Ubuntu v12.10.

In Eclipse CDT, I have these three C projects:

1. exeTop // executable that uses functions defined in libmiddle.a
2. libmiddle.a // static library that uses functions defined in libbottom.a
3. libbottom.a // standalone static library that doesn’t
   depend on any other libraries

In order to build libmiddle.a, I have to copy libbottom.a into libmiddle’s project folder (see instructions [here](http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234122/Spring2012/en/faq_Working%20with%20Eclipse%20CDT.html)), which makes sense as libmiddle.a depends on libbottom.a.

However when building exeTop, I not only have to link to libmiddle.a but to libbottom.a (which libmiddle.a has already linked to).

**Q1. Why is it required to link to libbottom.a from exeTop?**

**Q2. Are there any compiler or linker options I can use so that I can just link to libmiddle.a from exeTop?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "In order to build libmiddle.a, I have to link to libbottom.a, which makes sense as libmiddle.a depends on libbottom.a."  I do not think this is the case at all.  In fact, libmiddle.a can't really link against libbottom.a, because that's not how static libraries work on Linux.  Static libraries are just "archives" of object files, and don't have a feature that makes them depend on other static libraries.  Nor is it typical to stuff a static dependency into a static library itself.

For some more details, see [[UNIX] : Do I need to add all libraries in my project's makefile, that are used from a library, used in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664338/unix-do-i-need-to-add-all-libraries-in-my-projects-makefile-that-are-used)

Comment: To clarify, in order to build libmiddle.a without errors I have to copy libbottom.a into libmiddle’s project folder.

Comment: Why is that?  Building libmiddle should not require libbottom.  What's the command line that fails?

Comment: I was wrong!  Yes you are right.  I've just tried removing libbottom from libmiddle and libmiddle does build without libbottom.

Comment: Thanks for the link by the way.  So should I create shared objects (libbottom.so and libmiddle.so) and link to them from extTop instead?

Comment: You should do that if you don't mind deploying shared libraries alongside your executable.  But if you just want to avoid duplicate dependencies and keep the single, statically-linked binary, no need--you're already there.